# Finding pixels per inch in wxDC

Tags: wxwidgets

In wxWidgets, how can you find the pixels per inch on a wxDC? I'd like to be able to scale things by a real world number like inches. That often makes it easier to use the same code for printing to the screen and the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this help? (from the manual)

```
wxDC::GetPPI
wxSize GetPPI() const

Returns the resolution of the device in pixels per inch.
```

Answer (score 2):

...or [wxDC::GetSizeMM](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxdc.html#wxdcgetsizemm) which return the horizontal and vertical resolution in millimetres.